# Parse and modify JSON

Tags: groovy

I've a JSON with next structure and data:

```
[ {
  "id" : 716612,
  "type" : "ad",
  "stats" : [ {
    "day" : "2020-06-01",
    "impressions" : 1956,
    "clicks" : 1,
    "reach" : 1782
  }, 
  {
    "day" : "2020-06-13",
    "spent" : "73.32",
    "reach" : 1059
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : 414290,
  "type" : "campaign",
  "stats" : [ {
    "day" : "2020-05-21",
    "effective_cost_per_click" : "31.200",
    "effective_cost_per_mille" : "108.337"
  }, 
  {
    "day" : "2020-05-17",
    "impressions" : 1,
    "reach" : 1,
    "ctr" : "0.000",
    "uniq_views_count" : 1
  } ]
} ]
```

I need to map `id` and `type` from top level with data inside `stats` to get result like this:

```
[ {
  "id" : 716612,
  "type" : "ad",
  "day" : "2020-06-01",
  "impressions" : 1956,
  "clicks" : 1,
  "reach" : 1782
},
{
  "id" : 716612,
  "type" : "ad",
  "day" : "2020-06-13",
  "spent" : "73.32",
  "reach" : 1059
},
...
```

I tried with:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text)

def result = json.collectMany{ a ->
        a["stats"].collectMany{ b ->
            b.collect{
                [id: a.id,
                 type: a.type
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

But it returns only `id` and `type` fields without `stats`. I thought that I'm looping through `stat` and just adding needed fields from *above*. I guess I don't get the difference between `collectMany` and `collect`?

Answer (score 2):

You were close

You want to collect the `stat` plus the `id` and `type`, so you need:

```
def result = json.collectMany { a ->
    a.stats.collect { b ->
        [ id: a.id, type: a.type ] + b
    }
}
```